# run a script after 10 sec after page call

Tags: php, html

I want to execute a page script after after 5 seconds of executing a page

Means if i visit `http://localhost/form.php` then it wait for 5 seconds and then process the whole content of the page.

My page is this

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ex_smartcard2013");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  { 
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  id,name,course,amount FROM fess order by id desc limit 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
if($row['name'])
{ 

$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$course = $row['course'];
$amount = $row['amount'];

}
}
?>
<div style="display:none;">
<iframe id="ponyo_frame" name="ponyo_frame"></iframe>
<div class="ss-form"><form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1IDfOSwEcNYwvqxBHlGOTmPbZQrS7vr7Q1xw77UBVLUc/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="ponyo_frame" onsubmit=""><ol style="padding-left: 0">

<input type="text" name="entry.1312370642" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1312370642" dir="auto" title="">


<input type="text" name="entry.1082361902" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1082361902" dir="auto" title="">



<input type="text" name="entry.234382219" value="<?php echo $course; ?>" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_234382219" dir="auto" title="">


<input type="text" name="entry.1270326869" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1270326869" dir="auto" title="">


</div></div><script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("ss-form").submit();
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "process the whole content of the page"?

Comment: means it will run the mysql query after 5 sec when i visit page

Comment: As stated below, this is not possible. PHP is executed when the page is loaded, it generates the output that will then be sent to the client. If you want to perform that query later, you will need to get familiar with JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: From what I read your code look like a beginner code. Some advices then. You should quickly split your code in different files, classes and function. You could also learn a lot by learning a framework, CodeIgniter is loved by many new comers for its learning curve. If you learn by yourself and are only starting, I guess Zend and Symfony (which I hate) are too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side, it processes a request, send a response and stop, every new request is a new program instance, when you're viewing a page, no PHP is running, it's running only when you're "requesting" content.

You have to do it client side with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        //some ajax call that will call another php script and trigger your MySQL query
        ...
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

If you need to get explanation on how to run an Ajax query please look at JQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (documentation) http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ (tutorial)

Comment: how to use this in above page

Comment: I won't write the full code but if you copy paste the code I've written in the page and place some `console.log("foo")` in the setTimeout callback (where the comment is). You should be able to see it 5000 seconds after page load in your browser console (Google that if you don't know what it is). Then you can either redirect your user to a page that does the query (windows.location.replace) or make an AJAX call as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<body>
   <div class="empty"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // The code throw javascript to render the page html
       $('.empty').append('
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="Type Here" />
            </form>
       ');
    }).delay(5000);
</script>
```

This is not a good practice but it will help you do what you nedd.
You'll also need to add jquery